# A possible bug in the review test system

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, review-audit

I was reviewing an answer and it was designed to make sure I was paying attention. But I quickly recognized it as a test. Look at the picture  [image: here]

Generally, it looks like

[image: this]

In the first picture, it did not display any other answers. I found that the answer shown here for review was an accepted answer and was also awarded a bounty on it. Is this a possible bug?

Comment: Not really; the review system is checking to see that you're paying attention and not just clicking through as fast as you can without actually *reviewing*.  So if you can spot incongruities with the question, you're reviewing carefully enough.  There are a few small signs that a given question is most likely a test like the one you've found.

Comment: @postmortes Yes, sometimes I get old answers to review  and I could spot it as a test question

Comment: As this is probably not the intended behaviour, I have marked this question as [meta-tag:status-review].  That being said, I think that @postmortes explained things pretty clearly---the review audits are meant to see if you are paying attention, and so little tells like this aren't really a big deal.

Comment: And note, status-reviewer, each and every day, I field posts in Late Answers, Reopen, and Low Quality, that I've previously successfully voted on, and so I vote again, up to four times on the same review audit question.

Comment: ... Considering your comment on the deleted answer, Infinity_hunter, that tag description is outdated and not correct. When moderators add that tag, it means that it's been brought to the staff's attention to look into and respond. It does not in any way indicate that we actually believe that there's something wrong that needs fixing. And, to be clear "needs further investigation" is exactly that - there's no known answer, it just needs to be looked into.

Comment: @amWhy If you'd like to mention a different bug, please do so - comments on tangentially related questions are not a place to bring bugs to our attention.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're in the Low quality posts queue where I understand your concern but what postmortes said in the comments is correct. We're mostly checking for robo-reviewing - people just pushing buttons without thinking about the correct response - and so we don't have much concern for these being easily recognized.

As a note, we've recently split the First posts queue into two separate queues (First questions, First answers) and this shouldn't be an issue there any longer.